Error :TF254078 No attachable database were found
Azure Devops Server 2022.2
I have upgraded the Test Environment with new Azure DevOps Server 2022.2, Then restore the tfs_configuration and tfs_DefaultCollection latest backup from another production server. Everything works fine.
I took a full Backup before upgrading the Azure DevOps Server from 2022.1 to 2022.2. I have restored a Collection database in SQL Server. Then I follow Restore data to a different server than the current one, Because I have deleted the Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection and Restored another latest from backup from another server.
Now, I want to attach this collection from “Attach Team Project Collection” in “Azure DevOps Server Administration Console”. It gives me Error that No attachable database were found.
How Can I attach this project collection ?
I run TfsConfig commands to register this collection database. Checked all necessary service account permissions.

To attach the collection using the database restored from the backup of another server, you need to follow the steps mentioned in the documentation "Move a project collection".
And as the documentation stated, the step "Detach the collection" must be done and cannot be skipped. Otherwise, you cannot attach the collection to any deployment of Azure DevOps Server except the one from which it originated.



I have detached this collection and took a full backup. Also I have database from scheduled backup. I think this detach collection is only for running collection not for backup database.

I hope there must be some tfsconfig command to register the new collection database in current tfs_Configueration database

@Herr_grun, The step "Detach the collection" should be taken first, then back up the collection database, and then restore/copy/move the database from the backup to the SQL Server of the new Azure DevOps Server, after that, you can do the step "Attach the collection". Try to follow the steps one by one mentioned in the documentation and do not skip any of them.
